# Rails merging fields in two way has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forum_users
  has_many :forums through: :forum_users
end

class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forum_users
  has_many :users through: :forum_users
end

class ForumUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forums
  belongs_to :users
end
```

ForumUser has an additional "permissions" field to designate what the user can and cannot do within a particular forum.

The problem is that the "permissions" field on ForumUser is much more difficult to access than fields on Rails models normally are. In an ideal world, I would be able to make requests like:

```
user = forum.users.first
user.permissions
```

But once it's assigned, the User doesn't even remember the Forum it was attained through in the first place. It seems like there has to be a simple and straightforward Rails way of doing this. If so, what is it?

Comment: Change your `belongs_to` relationships to singular. See note on [belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) association.

Comment: When you get the permissions, the forum should be assigned explicitly. For example, you can pass it as a parameter of the `permissions` method.

Comment: @vee, the plurals was a typo. I didn't cut and paste.

Comment: @chumakoff, yeah, I understand how to do that, I was just thinking that it's so unrailsy and there should be a way to make it part of the instantiated object.